# how to Convert string MAC Address to Hex

Tags: c#, .net

How can I convert a MAC address `string` like `00:18:4d:D0:9d:62` to a hex string like `466F7572746820466C6F6F72` in C#?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?  How does the MAC translate to that number?

Comment: Cool. What is your question?

Answer (score 9):

The MAC address is very nearly a hex string.  In fact, if you remove the ':' characters, you have a hex string.

```
 string hex = macAddress.Replace(":", "");
```

To the original question

> 00:18:4d:D0:9d:62

would simply be

> 00184dD09d62

and not the same as (or as long as)

> 466F7572746820466C6F6F72

My original reading of the question (which is probably incorrect) was that the OP wanted the *base 10* equivalent of the hex number.  If any other representation is desired, one can remove the colons with [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) and then parse the number using [Convert.ToUInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.touint64.aspx)

```
string hex = macAddress.Replace(":", "");
uint64 macAsNumber = Convert.ToUInt64(hex, 16);
```

The number can then be converted to a string in whatever format is desired.

Comment: @J.Steen: Not sure what you mean by "thing".  Added MSDN links for the methods I use in the answer.

Comment: @J.Steen He is just answering the question as stated.

Comment: Not sure if the OP might want something that separates the values in the resultant decimal...i.e. `(0F:0F)` becomes `(015015)` *or* if he wants it as you describe, which would give `3855`.

Comment: Isn't this simply converting it to a `long`? So it wouldn't at all match the OP's "requirement" of it being a hex string of some sort?

Comment: @J.Steen: Actually I misread.  Thought he wanted the *base 10* equivalent.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Question is absolutely not clear, anyway... you can do this but the result will mean NOTHING:

```
Int64 value = Int64.Parse(address.Replace(":", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Otherwise you can get back the correct address value as follows:

```
String[] splits = address.Split(new Char[] { ':' });

address = String.Empty;

foreach (String split in splits)
    address += Byte.Parse(split, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```