# How to convert a MAC address from string to unsigned int

Tags: c#

A MAC address ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)) is typically formatted in the form of 6 hexadecimal numbers separated by a semicolon, like  `14:10:9F:D4:04:1A`.

In C#, it can be passed around as a `string`, while some libraries manipulate these as a `UInt64` or `ulong`.

**Question**

What are the relationship between the `string`, hex representation, `ulong`, and how can I go from one to the other?

Answer (score 11):

#### MAC Address *is* HEX

As correctly described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14362009/218152):

> The MAC address is very nearly a hex string. In fact, if you remove the ':' characters, you have a hex string.

`14:10:9F:D4:04:1A` literally means `0x14109FD4041A`, only easier to read.

---

#### `string` to `UInt64` and back

A MAC address is made up of 6 bytes, 48 bits, fitting in an `UInt64` with 2 bytes to spare. Leaving out the MSB vs. LSB ordering complication, you can use the 2 methods below:

**Format into a string**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static string MAC802DOT3(ulong macAddress)
{
    return string.Join(":",
                        BitConverter.GetBytes(macAddress).Reverse()
                        .Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))).Substring(6);
}
// usage: var s = MAC802DOT3(0x14109fd4041a);
//        var s = MAC802DOT3(22061633504282);
//            s becomes "14:10:9F:D4:04:1A"
```

**Convert to an integer**

```
public static ulong MAC802DOT3(string macAddress)
{
    string hex = macAddress.Replace(":", "");
    return Convert.ToUInt64(hex, 16);
}
// usage: var m = MAC802DOT3("14:10:9F:D4:04:1A");
//            m becomes 22061633504282 (0x14109fd4041a)
```